# Problems listing /data/data using Magisk su binary

Tags: android, root

I've got a root enabled (Magisk) file browser app that worked until Adroid 11.

Specifically the problem is listing /data/data - there may be others. Now it seems that the system will not let be "see" any directories except the app's directory and com.google.android.gms.

I can list the entire contents of /data/data using "adb shell" and the same su binary (/system/bin/su).

Is there any way around this?